# count number of tuples without COUNT. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I would like to know if there is any way of counting the number of tuples in a table without actually using the COUNT function?

```
A             B         C
XXXX         YYYY       IIII
XXXX         SSSS       PPPP
RRRR         TTTT       FFFF
KKKK         AAAA       BBBB
```

If I would like to know how many times XXXX has appeared without using COUNT. Is is possible?

Comment: Why is it important not to use `COUNT`? If you know how many items you have, you will have to count them at some point, and doing it on the database is generally the most efficient way. And that's exactly what `COUNT` is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this count?

```
SELECT SUM(1) AS COUNT
  FROM SomeTable
 WHERE A = 'XXXX';
```

Or, if 'XXXX' can appear in the other columns:

```
SELECT SUM(1) AS COUNT
  FROM SomeTable
 WHERE (A = 'XXXX' OR B = 'XXXX' OR C = 'XXXX');
```

Comment: What an answer! Can you explain what does sum(1) do?

Comment: Sum(1) sums 1 for each record that complies with the where conditions. Basically it is the same as Sum(column_name) but using a constant.